# 500GB only showing 1.7GB in size after swapping it in and out of another PC to transfer files

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8.1, partition-recovery

I wanted to backup a hard disk drive so I pulled it out of PC 1 (Linux, [OpenELEC 5](http://openelec.tv)) and put it in PC 2 (Windows 8.1). There was only media/data on the hard disk drive, no OS.

Files copied successfully, put the hard disk drive back in PC 1 now the drive shows up as only having 1.7GB available and no files on it.

I thought it might be a partition thing, `parted print` shows:

```
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  500GB  500GB  primary  ntfs         boot
```

So I turned off the `boot` flag but that didn't fix it.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I have another hard disk drive in PC 1 which has `msftdata` in the `Flags` column. Both hard disk drives were added at the same time so I presume the settings should be the same.

I tried `set 1 msftdata on` but I got `parted: invalid token: msftdata`

Comment: You likely should edit in the exact Linux flavor.

Comment: Nothing in your description seems unusual. What do you need suggestions for? What are you trying to do? What do you think needs to be fixed? (Perhaps you just didn't explain what you mean by "drives show up as having 1.7GB available". Are you saying you mounted the partition?)

Comment: Thanks for your resposnses. 1. Edited in Linux flavour. 2. Files on the drive are no longer available and there is only 1.7GB of usable space when there should be 500GB. 3. I'll take a look at that answer.

Comment: @barro32 You're not making any sense You say there should be 500GB of usable space, but there's a 500GB partition. Is it a 1TB drive? Also you've never explained *what* had 1.7GB available on it. If it's a 500GB drive with a 500GB partition, there might be 1.7GB available as the drive might be slightly larger than the partition. You say the files aren't on the drive, but you haven't explained where you looked for them. Did you mount the partition?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The drive is 500GB and only has 1 partition. There was about 200GB of data on the drive that I cannot access anymore ie. the drive appears to be empty. If I try to put anything on the drive larger than 1.7GB it won't let me because there is not enough space.

Comment: @barro32: You say it was a backup, so I assume you copied the files.  After the drive was mounted on PC2, how did you do that?  If you put the drive back into PC2 now, what does it show there?

Comment: @fixer1234: I ended up formatting the drive and I am currently copying the files back from PC2 to PC1 over the network. It's slow but at least I can be confident that it won't screw up the drive again. I'm going to close this question. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up formatting the drive in PC1 and copied the files back from PC2 over the network. I thought I could save some time but ended up wasting a lot more!
Windows must have done something to the drive which made OpenELEC not be able to read it or mount it or something.